# Why are Stack Exchange site rules for each site not easily visible on the front page?

Tags: discussion, rules

This is my usual experience:

"I want to post a question but I don't know what kind of questions are within the rules on this site. And since I don't want a question that took me 10 minutes to write to be instantly flagged as off-topic, deleted or down-voted into oblivion I won't post until I know the rules."

But the rules are nowhere to be found. The short site description is often not enough and doesn't include any extra information, for example Server Fault says "Q&A for server administrators" and nowhere does it say "Don't post questions about home servers on Server Fault" etc.

With the increasing amounts of new users wouldn't it be a good idea to have the rules defined on the front page of each site like on reddit for example?

Comment: Isn't that in [What is on-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? And 10 minutes to write a question and post it doesn't seem an awful lot of minutes, specially if you included searching for duplicates in that 10 minutes ...

Comment: It's odd that you'd claim you can't see this information when you're forced to have indicated that you read through the help center before you're even allowed to post questions on the site.  Also, you should be spending a *lot* more than 10 minutes writing a question for it to be a good question.

Comment: It is apparently, I've spent the last 15 minutes staring at the interface trying to find some information and I couldn't find anything. I still think this should not be buried in obscure drop-down menus. And should instead be easily visible since it's the primary issue with new questions. How should've I known that going to Help>Help centre>Asking>What is on topic? is where the information can be found as a new user?

Comment: Once you've joined a community and found the help center, it should not be hard to find it on the next site. Also, consider taking the [tour] on each site.

Comment: @Servy Right, I'm sure you also read every licence agreement when you install software and every popup message when you login into a service. I think the information should be in a much more visible place. And as to the 10 minutes it's arbitrary, you can write a good question in 5 minutes if it's a short question. So, I disagree.

Comment: @dcweaver01 You don't need to *just* find that one page.  If you're looking for info on the site's rules, clicking, "help" would be enough, so it's not 4 links deep, it's just one link, "help".  And, again, new users will have been *specifically* linked to that page when they tried asking a question, and would have been forced to indicate that they'd looked through the help center.  They can't *not* see it, they can only refuse to read it.

Comment: @dcweaver01 But this isn't a licence agreement, nor a terms and conditions.  It's the instructions for how to ask a question, which is being shown to you when you try to ask a question.  It doesn't really get any more obvious than that.  If people don't read it, there's really nothing more the site can do to help them; as they're not going to read anything.  And no, I don't suspect that very many good questions could be written in 5 minutes.  A question that short is almost certainly not sufficiently thought out and carefully written.

Comment: @Servy But that's simply not how people use the internet. I entered the site, clicked on <Join site> and then asked myself "Ok, where can I find the rules?" I personally don't know anyone that reads every popup and tooltip. Again, I think reddit does it well. You create account, log in, and all the rules are always visible on the sidebar. Also, I wasn't asked for anything before asking the question. It just brings me straight into the editor.

Comment: @dcweaver01 Okay.  So in asking yourself where to find the rules you completely ignored the "help" button?  That didn't seem like a good place to find information about how the site works?

Comment: @Servy Yep that's my point, It wasn't obvious. I clicked on help, looked at the entries and all I was was "Tour" - No "Help centre" - That's probably about customer service, "Meta" - No, "About us" - No, "Business" - No. And I just clicked away. Looking for "Forum rules" or "What can I ask" or "Question rules" or something obvious like that.

Comment: Now that I know where to find it I won't have a problem with it. But I don't think it does a good job of being obvious. And judging by how many new users don't post questions according to the rules, they must have trouble finding it too.

Comment: Most new users don't look, so attributing off topic closed first questions to rules being hard to find isn't reasonable.

Comment: But the bottom line is that nobody benefits from the rules being hidden in the help menu and not being visible on the front page.

Comment: I think this is something you will find helpful... http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903/284336 Helping new users with their first experience on SE is a huge priority... but there are better ways to achieve it and these are being considered.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you think "help center" is for customer service... It's where you go to get help including the rules... and it's where all the answers you're searching for are... Would you call this something else?

Comment: @Catija Well, skimming through the menu that's what I thought it was, so I didn't click it, since Help Centre sounds generic. And I thought it had to do with customer service issues and complaints.

Comment: I like the post you linked, sounds exactly like what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Danchm01 So you were having trouble finding your way around the site, so you decided that the "tour" wasn't for you, because you already know how to find what you wanted...you didn't need any help, so you didn't want to go to the help center...(and even if you thought that the help center was for customer service, despite it not saying that, and without looking at it, customer service *would* be an appropriate place to go if you were having trouble finding what you wanted on a site)...meta, "discuss the working and policies of the site" why is that a no if you want to know the site policies?

Comment: @Servy I think you're making the same wrong assumption again. People don't have time to read everything. I use dozens of sites on regular basis I don't have 3 hours to spare reading through all the documentation available on the site. I have things to do. I want to quickly find the information I need and get to the point. Reading through all the help manuals Is not an optimal way to find crucial information especially when you don't know if what you are looking for is even in the help manuals.

Comment: @Danchm01 You're whole point here is that you went out of your way to look for the help manuals and couldn't fine them.  Now you're saying that you couldn't be bothered to read them.  Yes, I'm well aware that, to a close approximation, nobody ever reads any of the information provided to them.  The information is readily accessible for those that are willing to read it though.

Comment: @Servy I went out of my way to find the site rules, I didn't know they were in the help manuals, and I didn't have the time to read through the help manuals in hopes finding what I was looking for. I don't see whose side are you arguing for because no one benefits from hiding the necessary information in menus.

Comment: see also: [Usability issues for first-time Stack Exchange users - a micro-study](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279661/usability-issues-for-first-time-stack-exchange-users-a-micro-study)

Comment: @Danchm01 The rules aren't hidden somewhere inside the help pages; the help pages *are* the site rules.